# How data consistency is preserved including transactions and PK and FK

Tags: sql, transactions, primary-key

How data consistency is preserved  between Primary Key and Foreign key during transactions

Comment: Do you mean how primary key and foreign key relations  are kept intact?

Comment: Yes, by transactions, primary key and foreign key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add foreign key to some table ,SQL uses specific operators to  verify conistency

**Demo:**

**Table Creation scripts:**

```
create table pktest
(
pk int not null primary key
)

create table FKtest
(
fk int
CONSTRAINT fkconstarint FOREIGN KEY (fk)     
REFERENCES pktest(pk)  
)
```

--Now insert some data into primary key table

```
insert into pktest
    select 2
```

Now insert some valid data into Foreign key table

```
insert into fktest
    select 2
```

Lets look at execution plan,using showplan_text on

```
 > |--Assert(WHERE:(CASE WHEN NOT [Pass1008] AND [Expr1007] IS NULL THEN (0) ELSE NULL END))
       |--Nested Loops(Left Semi Join, PASSTHRU:([test].[dbo].[FKtest].[fk] IS NULL), OUTER REFERENCES:([test].[dbo].[FKtest].[fk]), DEFINE:([Expr1007] = [PROBE VALUE]))
            |--Table Insert(OBJECT:([test].[dbo].[FKtest]), SET:([test].[dbo].[FKtest].[fk] = [@1]))
            |--Clustered Index Seek(OBJECT:([test].[dbo].[pktest].[PK__pktest__0425A276]), SEEK:([test].[dbo].[pktest].[pk]=[test].[dbo].[FKtest].[fk]) ORDERED FORWARD)
```

**Decoding the above plan:**

1.seek into fktest and return inserted value as `Expr1007`
2.Then probe into pktest using `Expr1007` and return if the value found as `Pass1008`

Then Assert checks ,if `Expr1007` or `Pass1008` is not null then return `0` and continue executing

What is `Expr1007` is null ,the nested loops will return null,so we can continue executing

This is the Way Constraints are kept intact

when we create primary key with out unique key word,SQL internally adds uniquifier to make this unique and checks whether a duplicate is inserted

**References:**
https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/showplan-operator-of-the-week---assert/